# How to execute build script react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm attempting to build a webpack/react project, however I'm not entirely sure on how or why this project is erroring...

Command line suggests that my npm/node might be outdated, but I just downloaded the stuff yesterday so I don't think that's the problem. New with react, appreciate all the help!

package.json: (Error comes from `npm run build`, doesn't seem to like `--config`)

```
{
  "name": "annandale-bbsb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "annandale baseball/softball website",
  "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Riley",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin(
{
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = 
{
    entry: __dirname + '/app/index.js',
    module: 
    {
        loaders: 
        [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    output: 
    {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build/'
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

This generates this npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~prebuild: annandale-bbsb@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: annandale-bbsb@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/Riley/annandale-bbsb/node_modules/.bin:/Users/Riley/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
10 verbose lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/Riley/annandale-bbsb
11 silly lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack' ]
12 silly lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle annandale-bbsb@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: annandale-bbsb@1.0.0 build: `webpack —-config webpack.config.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid annandale-bbsb@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/Riley/annandale-bbsb
17 error Darwin 15.6.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
19 error node v6.11.0
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error annandale-bbsb@1.0.0 build: `webpack —-config webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the annandale-bbsb@1.0.0 build script 'webpack —-config webpack.config.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the annandale-bbsb package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     webpack —-config webpack.config.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs annandale-bbsb
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls annandale-bbsb
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Your quotes inside `webpack.config.js` are off - they aren't regular single quotes. Also, there's no need for the `--config` flag here.

Comment: updated, but still same error

Comment: Do you have webpack install globally? Might need to do `./node_modules/.bin/webpack`

Comment: webpack is installed globally... again, error woes continue

Comment: What happens when you run `webpack --config webpack.config.js` directly? Also, create-react-app has pretty much completely saved me from dealing with webpack, so consider moving to that. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Riley/annandale-bbsb/webpack.config.js'